# How to handle Recyclerview list item click event

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working with recyclerview but I am trying to intent to next activity but there is not setonlistitem method can any one tell how to redirect to next activity on click of list item,following is my snippet code can any one help me with that

```
public class SubcategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.subcatgory_listviews);


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarsubcategory_list);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewsubcategory);


        ItemData itemsData[] = { new ItemData("Help",R.drawable.logo),
                new ItemData("Delete",R.drawable.logo),
                new ItemData("Cloud",R.drawable.logo),
                new ItemData("Favorite",R.drawable.logo),
                new ItemData("Like",R.drawable.logo),
                new ItemData("Rating",R.drawable.logo)};


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemsData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: See following post [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) probably help

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK can you post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need implement `RecyclerView` as below [example](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/material/lists-cards.html) .
Then in your holder class, implement `OnClickListener`.
Then use `getAdapterPosition()` to get current position of clicked Item.